# Lists in Python 2.7 (compatible with 3.x)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a code, in that code, I'm asking for IP address (it can be anything random, since the code is just for show, in other words, doesn't do really anything), I split it using "." as the delimeter, and I want to check, that it has four segments, just like an IP has. I don't want to check contents of the segments, I just want to check, if it can be a real IP (I know there are more than one conditions for validity of IP but let's keep it simple).

How can I check, that a list has four "elements", without tripping off any python error. I can supply the part of code in question, if required.

Edit 1:
Thank you guys for that quick answer. Here's the code you asked for, slightly changed, and not working (the previous version didn't either)(I imported fnmatch from fnmatch and the functions are already defined):

```
if fnmatch(list.split("."), "[*,*,*,*]"):
    success()
else:
    fail()
```

I'm trying to get something, that will call success() when the list has four items, and fail() if it doesn't.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: You have two questions, the first asking for how to check whether a given string is an IP address and the second asking for how to find out if a list has 4 items.  You seem to have the right idea for the first question (splitting the string using "." as a delimiter), and your second can easily be answered yourself by referring to the Python docs for list types.  Try and experiment A bit more, and if you're still stuck you can post your code next time.

Comment: it's best to include examples of your code when you ask a question.  show an example of what you have and what you are trying to get.

Comment: @MorganThrapp I never wanted you to write code for me, if you've read this carefully, you'd knew, that all you had to do is ask for the code. So, I did just that. In case that was what you ment, you could have been more straight forward about that.

Comment: @ramius You see, the second question I'm asking is my real goal. I split string given through user input, and I'm trying to check if it has four octets (because that's what IP basically is, four octets/bytes delimeted by dots), I do that by checking if the list contains four items, if it does, there is a possibility that it is a valid IP. If it's not, then there is a possibility, that it can be a domain name, in which case, it has to be resolved later on. That I'll be working on after this.

Comment: @JanNovák Why are you using fnmatch (File Name Match) to check if the length of a list is 4? It seems like you may need to read a Python tutorial. Finding the length of an object is covered early on in any good tutorial.

Comment: @MorganThrapp Didn't think it applied for number of items in a list, but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a little more debugging here.  For instance, check that your split gives you what you want.  Second, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- this lists our expectations for posting.

Giving the actual input and error message would have given you an answer much sooner: you fed a list to fnmatch, which expects a string.  You're on the right track, but you can do this more simply.

```
def success():
    print "good"

def fail():
    print "bad"

list = "10.10.10.127"
fields = list.split(".")

print fields

if len(fields) == 4:
    success()
else:
    fail()
```

Do you also need to check that each field is entirely numeric?

Comment: Thanks, this one has worked for me. And it would be helpful to check if the fields are numeric. Thanks again.